# Spying on Backbone View callback method with Jasmine

Tags: backbone.js, view, jasmine, spy

I have the following view:

```
  ...
  var TreeView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: '#org-tree',

    initialize: function() {
      eventBus.on("route:change", _.bind(this.triggerFilterEvent, this));
    },

    render: function() { ... },

    foo: function() { console.log("foo"); },

    triggerFilterEvent: function(name) {
      this.foo();
      ...
    }

  });
  ...
```

My Spec looks the following:

```
 describe('TreeView', function() {
    var treeView = new TreeView();

    it('calls triggerFilterEvent when receiving a route:change', function() {
      spyOn(treeView, 'triggerFilterEvent');
      spyOn(treeView, 'foo');
      treeView.delegateEvents();
      eventBus.trigger("route:change", "test");
      console.log('TriggerCOunt:' + treeView.triggerFilterEvent.callCount);
      console.log('FooCount: ' + treeView.foo.callCount);
      expect(treeView.triggerFilterEvent).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });
  });
```

I added `treeView.delegateEvents()` as suggested in the following solution:
[SpyOn a backbone view method using jasmine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7899474/spyon-a-backbone-view-method-using-jasmine)

However my test still fails with:

```
LOG: 'triggerFilterEvent with: test'
LOG: 'Event has been triggered: route:change'
LOG: 'TriggerCOunt:0'
LOG: 'FooCount: 1'
Error: Expected spy triggerFilterEvent to have been called.
```

The method foo is called once as expected though, how come?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The issue is at the time you assign a spy on `triggerFilterEvent`, an event listener is already set to call the original function and not the spy (`initialize` is called when you initialize the view)

To get around that you can spy on the prototype, **before** you initialize the view :

```
spyOn(TreeView.prototype, 'triggerFilterEvent');
var treeView = new TreeView();
```